# Adding to my new branch

Tags: git, github

Noob here....

I cloned a git and then created a new branch in it. I just want to add an existing (Android) project to my newly created branch. Dunno why, but I'm a bit confused as to how to add the files to this branch. I know the basic syntax is "git add FILENAME", but do I have to add all of the files from this android project into the new branch folder in order to be able to add them to the branch?

Basically, I just want to add an entire project that I have in a totally separate folder on my computer into this branch. Help me? :-)

Comment: Wait...are you adding an unrelated project into a new branch? Or is the repo currently empty?

Comment: Is the existing android project also in a git repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just add them all that's what i do when i import trees into git

you've done:

```
git branch some_name_here
```

then do:

```
git checkout some_name_here
```

then add them:

```
git add some/file oh/another/over/here
git commit -m "Added small android project"
```

although normally separate projects call for separate repositories, but if these two things are really variants of the same concept then placing them in branches makes sense

Comment: can you take me step-by-step through the syntax for adding the project to the branch?

Comment: I think I'm realizing that it may not make sense to do this the way I'm trying to do (though I'm still not sure). When you create a branch - correct me if I'm wrong - you get a copy of the master files and then you edit or whatever and can update in that branch. But if you're both creating projects from scratch, you really want to just create a repo in your project folder and then push it or whatever. Make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to "checkout" the branch:

```
git checkout new_branch_name
```

After that, just copy and paste all the files you want and use `git add` to add the files to version control.
May I ask why do you want to add an entire new project to a branch? 
Before doing that, make sure you understand the git concept for branchs.
[This](http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html) link will help.

Comment: If the existing project is also in git as you assume, then he can just use [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html), no need to copy files.

Comment: I'm a total git noob here so lemme firstly apologize and then try to clarify. Essentially, my colleague and I are separately creating a very basic program, which will just showcase on feature (this is for educational purposes). So we each wanted to share our code and then compare notes. Basically, I have the Android project and I need him to be able to see the full thing, java classes, xml resources, etc. So I just want to add the entire (small) project to this new branch so he can take a look. The Android projec is not a git repo, Wim.